# How to include multiple precompiled headers in with c++20 (with modules enabled) in gcc or clang

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, c++20, c++-modules

In c++20, when enabling modules, each include is supposed to be encapsulated so that the ordering does not matter, and macros does not leak out etc.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124842/c20-import-statement-will-it-be-possible-to-use-multiple-preprocessed-hea) the question *if* it is possible to precompile multiple headers is yes.

My question now is: *How* do you do this: That is: How do i first precompile a set of headers and then make the compiler recognize them (all of them) as precompiled headers for my translation unit using c++20 modules, (using linux command line).

I would like to have solution for g++ but if it is only possible with clang, that answer would be ok.

Notice that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199127/every-c-header-in-a-project-as-a-precompiled-header) question probably is outdated.

Comment: g++ doesn't support modules yet, and clang has partial support only. You can take a look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Thanks! When looking for it, what is it called in the list?

Comment: No, sure. I just did not find anything specific the state of multiple precompiled headers.

Comment: Modules don’t *allow* multiple precompiled headers; they are an *alternative* technology that does not have the single-shot limitation.

Answer (score 2):

> How to include multiple precompiled headers ... in gcc

There is no way. As the documentation says:

> Only **one** precompiled header can be used in a particular compilation.

---

> (with modules enabled) in gcc

No released version of GCC supports modules at the moment of writing.

---

It is somewhat unclear how "include precompiled headers" is related to modules exactly, but I'm guessing that you may be interested in the "Using Prebuilt Modules" section of Clang documentation.